# Virtual environment shows pip of the main system

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual-environment

After I made a new virtual environment in python `python3 -m venv venv`, I did `pip install gtts` and by doing `pip freeze` I can verify that it was successfully installed. Also, I did activate the virtual environment before installing. On the pip freeze, the only thing that showed up is gtts, six, certifi, and other packages used by gtts.

Sometime later, after closing my cmd, I started the virtual environment again via `cd venv/Scripts` then `activate.bat`, and when I `pip freez`-ed it shows the libraries I have installed on the main system. I can say that because **Pillow**, **pynput**, **pygame**, etc. is there and **gtts** is not.

I tried reactivating it, and the same thing happened. When I `pip freeze`-ed on the main system, it works perfectly, and still no gtts can be found, meaning I didn't mix the two up. When I clicked the python.exe on the venv, and did `import gtts`, no error showed up, meaning that gtts **did** get installed on the venv.

Comment: did u activated the environ before pip installing? `venv/bin/pip install gtts`

Comment: if you activate your virtual env, and then do a `which pip` what do you get ?

Comment: 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. @dejdej

Comment: try `where pip` , after activating your venv

Answer (score 0):

When you did `python3 -m venv venv` it just created the virtual environment but you have to activate it by yourself, since you didn't activate it in the first time it installed gtts to the main python interpreter on your system, in the second time when you **activated** the venv you didn't see `gtts` there since it was installed onto the main interpreter.

Comment: ohh, sorry, I did activate the venv before I pip installed, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @TasuketeOnegaishimasu "After I made a new virtual environment in python python3 -m venv venv, I did pip install gtts and by doing pip freeze I can verify that it was successfully installed.", did you activate it in that step?

Comment: I did, I can still remember the pip freeze only showing a few number of libraries. Namely, six, certifi, gtts, and others. Pygame, pynput, and other libraries that I usually use in the main interpreter wasn't there, so I did manage to get inside the venv.